# Cannot get the return values of stored procedure mysql

Tags: mysql, zend-framework, stored-procedures, out

I want to get the out parameter of stored procedure using Zend framework

Here's the procedure

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE procedure getAllUsers( out sysUsers VarChar(50) )

BEGIN
DECLARE usersCursor CURSOR FOR SELECT username  FROM SYSTEM_USERS;
OPEN usersCursor ;
FETCH  usersCursor  INTO sysUsers ;
CLOSE usersCursor ; 

END//
DELIMITER ;
```

And here what I don through Zend framework

```
try {
        $db = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();
        $stmt = $db->query("CALL getAllUsers(@users)");

        //Returns an array containing all of the result set rows  
        $rows = $stmt->fetchAll();

        $stmt->closeCursor();
            print_r($rows);



    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo 'error ' . $e;
    }
```

an empty array returns!! how can I return a recursor form stored procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the problem without using the cursor I make like this

```
 DELIMITER //

 CREATE procedure getAllUsers( )

 BEGIN
  SELECT username  FROM SYSTEM_USERS;

 END//
DELIMITER ;
```